# React - use relative paths to static assets in CSS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I'm using create-react-app to build an interface for an Electron app. As such, the built React app essentially runs locally rather than from a server.

Naturally I have a load of SCSS being built by React, but as part of the build process my paths are changed from `url(../images/my_img.jpg)` to `url(/static/media/my_img.xyz.jpg)`

Obviously for a server environment where files would be stored at the root this is fine, but because my files are running locally the browser (Electron) can't locate the images.

I have set `"homepage": "./"` in package.json but this has had no effect.

Is there a way to ensure that built CSS uses relative paths rather than absolute?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, it's a bit of a hacky workaround, but for now what I've managed to do is...

1) I installed the "replace" NPM package in my project:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/replace

2) I then set up a postbuild script in package.json:

```
"postbuild": "replace 'static' '..' build/static/css/*"
```

It's not ideal, but it does the job!

Answer (score 0):

Try `"homepage": "."`

There are problems possibly to be encountered with `"homepage": "."` so it works in some cases, but It's not recommended.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to make a difference. Additionally the terminal output still says `The project was built assuming it is hosted at ./.`

Comment: Where are you compiling? Windows? If so, did you try .\

Comment: I'm compiling on macOS

Comment: Have you tried by putting nothing between quotes? Some people say that worked for them

Comment: That seems to make everything else absolute again, so my app can't find any bundled js or css

Comment: Can you try any of this? https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/527#issuecomment-263051964

Comment: Unfortunately no, the PUBLIC_URL variables can only be used in index.html not in css. I guess React / Webpack just can't handle relative assets in CSS.